# Using boolean from JSON for if statement

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have a var that equals true, but it seems that since it's from a JSON, it's not "actually" true.

This doesn't work:

```
<% sppf = Model.exists?(foo_id: foo.id) %>
#this translates to: true
#in the view-source

<script>
var sppf_boolean = <%= sppf.to_json.html_safe %>;
#this translates to: var sppf_boolean = true;
function loadJSONImage() {
  if (sppf_boolean)
  {
     #codey
  };
};
</script>
```

Tried to remove the `to_json.html_safe` but that didn't do that trick.  Also tried that with a combination of `(sppf_boolean === true)` and `(sppf_boolean == true)`

This does work:

```
<script>
var sppf_boolean = true;
function loadJSONImage() {
  if (sppf_boolean)
  {
     #codey
  };
};
</script>
```

In the source code, it shows `true` (or `false`).  Is there some difference from the true/false coming from ruby syntax?

I don't see any reasons on why this will not work.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Surely, just using

`var sppf_boolean = <%= Model.exists?(foo_id: foo.id) %>;`

should do the trick, am I missing anything?

Comment: Tried it, not working.  That's what I'm saying, there's something missing here I am not understanding.  All the same code works as long as i manually set it to true, but if I use the ruby code, which equals true, it won't work...

Comment: where have you place this code inside script tag? It should be at the bottom of your layout html file before the closing body tag in most cases.  If it's in a javascript file that will get precompiled, it may not work as expected, and will like throw compilation error if you are using asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work but to be sure, add console log.  Also, if you expect your function to be called, well maybe call it?  UPDATE: Use closure to insure you're variable names are not polluted in the global scope.

```
<script>
(function(){
  var sppf_boolean = <%= Model.exists?(foo_id: foo.id) %>;
  console.log(sppf_boolean);
  function loadJSONImage() {
    if (sppf_boolean)
    {
       #codey
    }
  }
  // but we have not called the function yet.  Should we? if so:
  loadJSONImage();    
}();
</script>
```

Comment: Okay we're getting somewhere.  In the console.log, it says false.... but right above it in the `var`, it shows `var sppf_boolean= true`

Comment: sounds like a possible global scope var name clash.  Try using a different var name? something surely not used elsewhere?

Comment: That;s gotta be it.  It's because it's based on variables in a loop

Comment: See updated answer, but sounds like using erb in your javascript may not work for your use case, and in general is not recommended.

Comment: You were right about the naming.  Because it's based on variables, I wasn't using the variable name so it was taking the last variable status